# Computer name is needed for "Data Source" parameter of dynamic connection string

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dynamic, connection-string

We are going to change the connection string in Settings.vb so we don't need to worry about what it is when our app runs on a different computer other than the development computer.

Our code looks like this:

```
Partial Friend NotInheritable Class MySettings

    Dim strComputerName As String
    Dim strConnectionString As String

    Private Sub MySettings_SettingsLoaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Configuration.SettingsLoadedEventArgs) Handles Me.SettingsLoaded

        '  strComputerName = 

        ' Build a new construction string.
        '---------------------------------
        strConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strComputerName & "\sqlexpress" & _
                              ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

        ' Change to the new connection string.
        '-------------------------------------
        Me.Item("Kemal_Business_SolutionConnectionString") = (strConnectionString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can you tell me how to obtain the computer name because we need that information to place into the "Data Source=" part of the connection string?

Update: Here is what the final coding looks like. Thanks everyone for your replies:

```
Partial Friend NotInheritable Class MySettings

    Dim strComputerName As String
    Dim strConnectionString As String

    Private Sub MySettings_SettingsLoaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Configuration.SettingsLoadedEventArgs) Handles Me.SettingsLoaded

        strComputerName = Environment.MachineName
        'strComputerName = My.Computer.Name

        ' Build a new construction string.
        '---------------------------------
        strConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strComputerName & "\sqlexpress;" & _
                              "Initial Catalog=""Kemal Business Solution"";" & _
                              "Integrated Security=True"

        ' Change to the new connection string.
        '-------------------------------------
        Me.Item("Kemal_Business_SolutionConnectionString") = (strConnectionString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you try a `.` or `(local)`? Also are you sure every single computer will have a named instance called `sqlexpress`?

Comment: Yes, all of them have it that way. We will be installing sqlexpress on the target machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or the far more arcane.

```
strComputerName = Environment.MachineName
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick responses. My.Computer.Name and Evironment.MachineName both worked. We are going to go with this Environment.MachineName. Which one is the prefered one?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. My is available in VB and joins together a bunch of related stuff you might want for say a Help About screen or a OS compatibility check. So you might find My handier if you need some more bits and pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using VB.net, you've got access to the `My` namespace, which makes this super-easy.

```
strComputerName = My.Computer.Name
```

Job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try any one of the following line of code. Here `Data Source=.;` indicates the database from the local computer

```
strConnectionString = "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

--OR--

```
strConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```